# Insert array data into database using Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have problem with this code..I want to extract data from flat file and store it into database. flat file format is like this:-

```
DT|00000001|TMDWH|UNIFI|00380520160|MAH SIEW YIN|11  |JALAN PP 2/8|TAMAN PUTRA PRIMA|PUCHONG|SELANGOR|47100|MALAYSIA|801110-14-5498||||||VOBB||A||11|JALAN PP 2/8|||TAMAN PUTRA PRIMA

DT|00000002|TMDWH|UNIFI|00322012091|JUNITA BINTI JAMAL|6 10 KONDOMINIUM FAJARIA|JALAN PANTAI BARU|KUALA LUMPUR|KUALA LUMPUR|WILAYAH PERSEKUTUAN|59200|MALAYSIA|800129-09-5078||||||VOBB||A|||JALAN PANTAI BARU|6|KONDOMINIUM FAJARIA|KUALA LUMPUR
```

Code:

```
public void massageData(String tmp) {

        String RecordType = "";
        String RecordNumber = "";
        String sourceSystemId = "";
        String targetSystemId = "";
        String TelNo = "";
        String Name = "";
        String Addr1 = "";
        String Addr2 = "";
        String Addr3 = "";
        String TownCity = "";
        String State = "";
        String PostalCd = "";
        String Country = "";
        String NewICNo = "";
        String OldICNo = "";
        String PassportNo = "";
        String BRN = "";
        String Latitude = "";
        String Longitude = "";
        String ServiceType = "";
        String IndicatorType = "";
        //add
        String CreateDate = "";
        String Filler = "";
        String CRNL = "";

        String HouseNo = "";
        String LotNo = "";
        String StreetName = "";
        String AptNo = "";
        String BuildingName = "";
        //add
        String LowID = "";
        String HighID = "";

        String SectionName = "";

        tmp = tmp.replace("\""," ");            // remove " with blank
        tmp = tmp.replace("\'","\'\'"); 
        String[] recArray = tmp.split("\\|");

        RecordType = recArray[1].trim();    
        RecordNumber = recArray[2].trim();
        sourceSystemId = recArray[3].trim();
        targetSystemId = recArray[4].trim();
        TelNo = recArray[5].trim();
        Name = recArray[6].trim();
        Addr1 = recArray[7].trim();
        Addr2 = recArray[8].trim();
        Addr3 = recArray[9].trim();
        TownCity = recArray[10].trim();
        State = recArray[11].trim();
        PostalCd = recArray[12].trim();
        Country = recArray[13].trim();
        NewICNo = recArray[14].trim();
        OldICNo = recArray[15].trim();
        PassportNo = recArray[16].trim();
        BRN = recArray[17].trim();
        Latitude = recArray[18].trim();
        Longitude = recArray[19].trim();
        ServiceType = recArray[20].trim();
        IndicatorType = recArray[21].trim();
        //add
        CreateDate = recArray[22].trim();
        Filler = recArray[23].trim();
        CRNL = recArray[24].trim();
        //

        HouseNo = recArray[25].trim();
        LotNo = recArray[26].trim();
        StreetName = recArray[27].trim();
        AptNo = recArray[28].trim();
        BuildingName = recArray[29].trim();
        //add
        LowID = recArray[30].trim();
        HighID = recArray[31].trim();
        //
        SectionName = recArray[32].trim();

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        logger.info("masuk messageData");
        // get actual telephone number
        String actualMSISDN = parseMSISDN(TelNo);

            String [] aNo = getAreaCode(actualMSISDN).split("\\|");
            String iCtr = getiCtr(actualMSISDN);
            iCtr = recArray[0].trim();
            String stateCode = lookupStateCode(State);
            String  sQuery = "insert into DATA_999 (ID,RecordType,RecordNumber,SourceSystemApplicationId,TargetApplicationId,TelNo,Name,HouseNo,StreetName,AppartmentSuite,TownCity,State,PostalCode,Country,NewIC,OldIC,PassportNo,BRN,LatitudeDecimal,LongitudeDecimal,ServiceType,IndicatorType,CreateDate,Filler,Cr_Nl,HouseNo_New,LotNo_New,StreetName_New,AptNo_New,BuildingName_New,LowIDRange,HighIDRange,SectionName) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try {   
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                // insert post process data to data_999 table
                logger.info("start Query");

                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
                stmt.setString(0,iCtr);
                stmt.setString(1,RecordType);
                stmt.setString(2,RecordNumber);
                stmt.setString(3,sourceSystemId);
                stmt.setString(4,targetSystemId);
                stmt.setString(5,TelNo);
                stmt.setString(6,Name);
                stmt.setString(7,Addr1);
                stmt.setString(8,Addr2);
                stmt.setString(9,Addr3);
                stmt.setString(10,TownCity);
                stmt.setString(11,State);
                stmt.setString(12,PostalCd);
                stmt.setString(13,Country);
                stmt.setString(14,NewICNo);
                stmt.setString(15,OldICNo);
                stmt.setString(16,PassportNo);
                stmt.setString(17,BRN);
                stmt.setString(18,Latitude);
                stmt.setString(19,Longitude);
                stmt.setString(20,ServiceType);
                stmt.setString(21,IndicatorType);
                //add
                stmt.setString(22,CreateDate);
                stmt.setString(23,Filler);
                stmt.setString(24,CRNL);
                //
                stmt.setString(25,HouseNo);
                stmt.setString(26,LotNo);
                stmt.setString(27,StreetName);
                stmt.setString(28,AptNo);
                stmt.setString(29,BuildingName);
                //add
                stmt.setString(30,LowID);
                stmt.setString(31,HighID);
                //
                stmt.setString(32,SectionName);

                //stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
                int dbStat = stmt.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException s){
                logger.error(s.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {if (stmt != null) stmt.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
                try {if (conn != null) conn.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
```

I really2 hope anyone here can help me.

Current result:

> No data store into database, the code was successfully compiled!

Expected result

> All the data will store into database DATA_999.

Comment: Why putting javascript tag here?

Comment: You should post here an exception you get (instead of just logging the message, log the whole exception in logger.error(s.getMessage())

Comment: Dear Mark Brammik, I am sorry because tag javascript..huhu..erm, I didnot get any exception. The log doesnot show anything. That is my big problem now. That is why I don't know what is going on and what is the problem with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL API, unlike every other java API I can think of which is [zero-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based), is one-based - meaning it starts counting from one. Your code is trying to set the zeroth field, which should be exploding.

As a side note, because there's hardy any special processing for each field, you could replace all that code with just a few lines by simply iterating over the fields and setting the stmt params - ie don't use variables for each field:

```
// fyi, the regex of this split trims automatically
String[] fields = tmp.replace("\""," ").replace("\'","\'\'").trim().split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
// Do any special field processing (most need none)
field[0] = getiCtr(parseMSISDN(field[5])); // for example - just do what you need
// Now set all the SQL params
int col = 0;
for (String field : fields) {
    stmt.setString(++col, field); // Note: SQL API is 1-based (not zero-based)
}
```

Comment: Dear Bohemian, thank you for your suggestion but could you please tell me why the data cannot store into database?..what is the problem with this code?

Comment: @Siti See comments in my code: `// Note: SQL API is 1-based (not zero-based)`. There is no field `0`, it starts counting from field `1`

Comment: Dear Bohemian, thank you for the info. I have 1 question. How to get length from each array. field[5].length?

Comment: `field[5]` is just a `String`, so `field[5].length()` would be its length

Comment: Dear Bohemian, I got 0 for the length..Something goes wrong maybe.what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes for prepared statements are 1-based:

Change `stmt.setString(0,iCtr);` to `stmt.setString(1,iCtr);`. (And adjust the following)

And please post the exception you get. It will give us more hints what might went wrong

EDIT:

Are all fields in your table of type `varchar`? There are values in your lines that might be modeled as `int`s.

Comment: Dear Hage, I already change it but the result is still same. The data is not store into DATA_999. any error in my code?..I really need help on this matter.. really appreciate it..:)

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Are your running the program from command line? Maybe you can print the exception with `s.printStackTrace(System.out);` ?

Comment: Dear Hage, what is the different between print StackTrace with the logger.info from my code?

Comment: Dear Hage, I am using Sql plus.

Comment: I don't know what your `logger` is... And printStackTrace prints the full stack trace (i.e. all method calls) instead  of just the exception message. Also, does the message `No data store into database,...` come from SQL Plus or is it generated somewhere in your code?

Comment: I just check inside the database and the no data inside. Logger will save any print msg inside .log file. I am also not so sure about this, they just give  this code and ask me to do it using the current setting.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless you should check what the stack trace contains. There might be some nested exception that gives you a hint of what went wrong.